# Making An "Any Key" Interuptable Python Timer

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, interrupt

I am trying to make a simple timer which counts up until it is interrupted by keyboard input.

right now I am using CTRL+C to stop the timer, but I would like to do something more simple like hitting space or enter or "any key".  I hear this can be done with the threading module, but after several attempts I clearly do not know what I am doing with that.

this is my current code:

```
def countup():
    try:
        a=0
        for i in range(1000000) :
            print i,'\r',
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
         Z = raw_input("restart timer?" )
         if Z == "Y" or Z == "y" :
             countup()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [thread](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html) and [terminal capabilities](http://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html) you can write (press any key to stop):

```
import thread
import time

def read_key():
    import termios
    import sys
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    new = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    new[3] &= ~(termios.ICANON | termios.ECHO) # c_lflags
    c = None
    try:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, new)
        c = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, old)
    return c

def input_thread():
    read_key()
    thread.interrupt_main()

def countup():
    try:
        thread.start_new_thread(input_thread, ())
        for i in range(1000000):
            print i
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        Z = raw_input("restart timer? ")
        if Z == 'y' or Z == 'Y':
            countup()
```

Let's clarify a bit:

[`thread.start_new_thread()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread) create a new thread using `input_thread()` as start function. While [`thread.interrupt_main()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.interrupt_main) raise `KeyboardInterrupt` in the main thread.

[`termios.tcgetattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html#termios.tcgetattr) return the current terminal attribute. `~termios.ICANON` unset the [canonical](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Canonical-or-Not.html) mode and `~termios.ECHO` prevent input print then [`termios.tsetattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html#termios.tcsetattr) act the change.

Alternatively, on Windows, `getch()` from [msvcrt](http://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html) can be use in place of `read_key()`

```
def input_thread():
    msvcrt.getch()
    thread.interrupt_main()
```

---

### Reference

- [Thread module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html)
- [Termios module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html)
- [Msvcrt module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html)

Comment: excellent. For the press any key I loaded the MSVCRT module and replaced the raw_input() function with char=msvcrt.getch().  then used an if function for char which would always be false when a key was pushed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code as it stands:

1. You aren't checking for keyboard input during the for loop, so the program isn't going to notice if you type random characters to stdin.
2. KeyboardInterrupt exceptions are thrown specifically when the interrupt key (i.e. Ctrl-C) is pressed.

The problem is that you need to attempt to read from stdin, but not wait until input appears there if there isn't any to begin with. [This page](https://repolinux.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/non-blocking-read-from-stdin-in-python/) provides a good description of how to do this.

Based on the link above, this code should do the trick to make the countup stop if you hit enter:

```
import sys 
import select 
import time

def countup():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print i
        i += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        while sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
            line = sys.stdin.readline()
            if line:
                r = raw_input("Restart?")
                if r.lower() == "y":
                    countdown()
                else:
                    break

 countup()
```